# Can a Guildgate be tapped for colorless?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can [Izzet Guildgate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=270961) be tapped for colorless mana? For example, could I tap 7 Guildgates to cast [Karn Liberated](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Karn%20Liberated)?

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games! If you're asking this question, you've probably missed learning some fundamentals about the game. I suggest you read the [Basic Rulebook](http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/tcg/article.aspx?x=magic/rules) (first link on the page) - it's a basic coverage of all the rules, in more depth than the booklet which comes with starter decks.

Comment: This site welcomes basic rules questions. Can whomever voted to close please explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a guildgate to help pay for Karn, but it doesn't involve colorless mana.

When you see a grey circle with a number mana symbol in a cost, like the {7} in Karn's casting cost, that's actually called a *generic* mana cost. You can spend any color of mana to pay for that cost. So you can, say, tap an Izzet Guildgate for red (or blue) mana and use that to pay for one of that seven mana.

Colorless mana, on the other hand, is what's *produced* when you see something like "add {1} to your mana pool", again with the grey circle with a number, for example on [Tomb of the Spirit Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tomb%20of%20the%20Spirit%20Dragon). You can use that to pay for generic mana costs too - so you *could* use colorless mana to cast Karn, but you don't have to. Any color will do.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit unfortunate that the same symbol has different meanings based on context. Maybe in some alternate universe, generic costs are designated with * or something.

Comment: One way to think about it is that mana sources that produce colorless mana doesn't **provide** any color of mana, and generic mana costs don't **require** any color of mana.